# How to find existence of association with certain attributes with optimal SQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Suppose you have two ActiveRecord models - Problem and ProblemSet.

You have a @problem_set object, and you want to check if it has a problem with a certain title attribute.

You could say:

```
@problem_set.problems.where(:title => "Adding Numbers").any?
```

which returns `true`, by running the optimal SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "problems" INNER JOIN "problem_sets_problems" ON "problems"."id" = "problem_sets_problems"."problem_id" WHERE "problem_sets_problems"."problem_set_id" = 1 AND "problems"."title" = 'Adding Numbers'
```

However, if @problem_set was in memory, ie, you got @problem_set by:

```
@problem_set = ProblemSet.new()
@problem_set.problems << Problem.new(:title = "Adding Numbers")
```

Then you will not be able to find the problem (ie. it returns false!). This is because the following SQL is run:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "problems" INNER JOIN "problem_sets_problems" ON "problems"."id" = "problem_sets_problems"."problem_id" WHERE "problem_sets_problems"."problem_set_id" IS NULL AND "problems"."title" = 'Adding Numbers'
```

A possible way to perform the check correctly for both persistent objects and in-memory objects, is:

```
@problem_set.problems.map(&:title).include? "Adding Numbers"
```

Which correctly returns `true` in both cases. However, in the case of a persistent object, it runs the non-optimal SQL (which retrieves all problems):

```
SELECT "problems".* FROM "problems" INNER JOIN "problem_sets_problems" ON "problems"."id" = "problem_sets_problems"."problem_id" WHERE "problem_sets_problems"."problem_set_id" = 1
```

**Question: Is there a way to use the same code to check for both persistent objects and in-memory objects, while running optimal SQL code?**

Note that a solution which checks for object persistence is permitted (but I don't see how to check the dirtiness of the collection). However, it should still work if a persistent object is modified (ie. the association collection attribute becomes dirty, and therefore the result from an SQL query would be out-of-date).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally worked it out.

Browsing through obscure rails functions, I found the `persisted?` method. You can use `@problem_set.persisted?` to check if the object is persistent or in-memory only.

So the answer is:

```
if @problem_set.persisted?
  @problem_set.problems.where(:title => "Adding Numbers").any?
else
  @problem_set.problems.map(&:title).include? "Adding Numbers"
end
```

The remaining question is, what about persistent objects where the association collection is dirty? Well, by experimentation, I found out that it doesn't really happen. When you add an object to the collection, for example, one of the following:

```
@problem_set.problems << Problem.new(:title => "hello")
@problem_set.problems.push Problem.new(:title => "hello")
```

ActiveRecord immediately saves the data. Similarly, it immediately destroys the row from the associations table when you say:

```
@problem_set.problems.delete(@problem_set.problems[2])
```

That means, although there is no such method as `@problem_set.problems_changed?`, if there was, the current implementation would result in `problems_changed?` always returning `false`.

In effect, the `collection<<`, `collection.push`, `collection.delete` methods auto-save (ie. calls `save` automatically).